What does stable/meta-stable vacuua actually mean in theories with spontaneously broken symmetries?
In SSB, there exists a scalar field has non-zero VEV. So we redefine the fields to have zero VEV for several reasons. But what is the vacuum used in calculation of the correlators in this field and shifted field? Are they the same? I thought they are the same, but then there are discussions of "stable" and "metastable" vacuua. Vacuua are supposed to be states, but I see that only the field configurations are getting shifted. What about states in which the correlators are calculated? Are they changed too? What do these metastable/stable/unstable vacuum states mean mathematically in the particular context I am asking? For example when they speak of degenerate vacuua, there must be a notion of acting some Hamiltonian operator on some states: which states? Are these the states annihilated by the annihilation operator of the unshifted field?

Do different field configurations in classical field theory correspond to different vacuua in the quantum theory?
